# How to build ipa (iOS App Store Package) from PWA(Progressive web application)

Tags: ios, progressive-web-apps

My PWA(which is written in angular) application works fine but it certainly has some weird visual anomalies, so I want to make it as a build (to publish into AppStore, thinking about this in the future), is there any way to create a .ipa build?

Comment: look into capacitor: https://capacitorjs.com/

Comment: You can covert your website into iOS native app using tools like Cordova. But you cannot run service worker in iOS native app. Anyway you don’t need service worker if you are building native app.